# Fullcalendar popover is empty (using eventLimit)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, popover

I've been trying to understand why the popover appears empty when I click "+ x events".

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elpmelo/100f7fap/2/) wherein I reproduced the error. I used the [debug template](http://jsfiddle.net/arshaw/3E8nk/) as the base for this test.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventLimit: 5, //or any truthy value
    ...
});
```

Comment: try to change event source

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/100f7fap/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at it more, I figured it out. When using fullCalendar with version 2.1.1 the **start** (and/or) **end** must be set using [moment](http://momentjs.com) objects. Then the events appear in the popover.

The right way to declare a event:

```
events: [
    {   
        start:moment('2014-11-06 22:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'),
        end:moment('2014-11-06 23:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'),
        title:'Test',
        allDay:false
    }]
```

Comment: I tried to use your solution to fix the jsfiddle you posted but it doesn't work. Any idea what might be wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/808/

Comment: If you look carefully to the eventData.start it's in milisecond format, and you are formating it to date. Also notice that de eventData.end it's the duration of the event and not the timestamp of it, so you got to sum the start with end. @RichardHermanson verify it here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/814/)

Comment: Thanks, so it seems that if end if before start then nothing shows in the popover? I'll check for this in my own code

Comment: Yes, there is also that into consideration. The end _moment_ must be after the start _moment_. I only realized after a while, that  implementing with this version of FullCalendar its imperative to use [Moment](http://momentjs.com) objects correctly.

Comment: I discovered that it doesn't actually have to be a moment and the problem also includes start==end. Edited the answer